# iPhone - Refreshing TableView VC from higher ViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have ViewController (A) with TableView where each row is a directory name. Each row is pushing a new ViewController (B). Inside ViewController B I am running method to delete the currently opened directory. However, when I pop the view and go back to TableView I obviously still have this directory on list. How can I fix it?

**How can I refresh the TableView while going back in navigation?**

And no, simple `[self.tableView reloadData]` inside `-viewWillAppear` doesn't really work.

Code:

My -viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    self.arrFolders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self allFilesInDocuments:docDir];
}
```

-allFilesInDocuments is just adding items to array (`[arrFolders addObject:folder];`).

Inside `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I add data with

```
cell.textLabel.text = [arrFolders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData]; its easy way to refresh the table.

Comment: did u even read the whole question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a NSNotification.

In the viewDidLoad of ViewController (A) register for a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deletedRow:) name:@"deletedRow" object:nil];
```

Also add the selector function:

```
-(void) deleteRow:(NSNotification *)notif{
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Finally in the child view controllers, in your Delete function post the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defautCenter] postNotificationName:@"deletedRow" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

An edit to the datasource and a reload in -viewWillAppear should of worked though failing this you could perform the update via an parent view controller call or an NSNotification.

Comment: NSNotification is better, saves you the unnecessary reloads when nothing was deleted.

Comment: Making a custom delegate for the item view and assigning it to the parent, that would work as well, bit more code involved but generally cleaner.