# Call [tableView reloadData]; on a viewController from a modalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a modalViewController that comes up over the top of a viewController with a tableView. When the user clicks a button on the modalViewController I want to reload the tableView within the viewController with this:

```
[tableView1 reloadData];
```

I do not want to put the reload in the viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear methods as they get called when i do not need the tableView to reload (i.e. when the user clicks the back button to return to the tableView).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Go through Notifications or Delegate.

Comment: Hi Anil, Im not exactly sure how to do that. Do you have any examples or recommendations for getting started?

Comment: @Brandon Go for Delegate. That will be really helpful to you.

Comment: thanks @Bhargavi - Im not actually sure what that means or how to do it. Can you give me any pointers?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers

Comment: Yes follow steps given in link by Anil . And implement delegate method in your ViewController with reloadData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Notification like bellow Method:-

Create `NSNotificationCenter` at yourViewController's `ViewdidLoad` Mehod

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(ReloadDataFunction:)
                                                     name:@"refresh"
                                                   object:nil];

  [super viewDidLoad];

}
-(void)ReloadDataFunction:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [yourTableView reloadData];

}
```

Now you can Call this Notification from your modelViewController BackButton or else you want from calling this Refresh notification like putting this line of code:-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refresh" object:self];
```

**NOTE:** `postNotificationName:@"refresh"` this is a key of particular Notification

Answer (score 2):

Try

1) write one method which `reloads` the `table data`.

2) Call it on the back `button` clicked.

Comment: Hi Girish, I have the method built. I want to call it when the user clicks a button on a modal view, not the back button. Do you know how to go about doing this?

Comment: i believe Girish means create your reload method inside the viewcontroller (that has your tableview) and call that from the modalviewcontroller

Comment: In that case create one delegate which automatically calls when you clicked the button.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato you are right but if he did not want this, then used delegate as I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I guess I just don't know how to call a method on one viewController from another

Comment: @Brandon call the method using the object of view controller as [vc reloadTableDate]; as vc is the obj of view controller.

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic delegate pattern problem, in your modal view controller you need a delegate reference to the current view controller presenting it

```
//Modal
@protocol ModalVCDelegate
- (void)tappedBackButton;
@end

@class ModalVC: UIViewController
@property id<ModalVCDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation
- (void)backButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.delegate) 
        [self.delegate tappedBackButton];
}
@end
```

Now, in your presenting VC, just process this delegate message

```
//Parent VC
- (void)showModal
{
    ModalVC *vc = [ModalVC new]; 
    vc.delegate = self;
    //push
}

- (void)tappedBackButton
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    //close modal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate . If find it more harder then alternative is to use `NSNotificationCenter`. You can see accepted answer for [Refreshing TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567491/iphone-refreshing-tableview-vc-from-higher-viewcontroller). This is really very short, easy and understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

Make a Button and click on this button and than you can reload your data.
This button make custom and use it on background.

```
  - (IBAction)reloadData:(id)sender
    {
         [tblView reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
You can use NSNotification to refresh table on ViewController.

Inside viewController :

-(void)dealloc{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[super dealloc];
}

Write code in viewDidLoad:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(reloadMainTable:) 
        name:@"ReloadTable"
        object:nil];




- (void) reloadMainTable:(NSNotification *) notification
{
  [tableView reload];
}


Inside ModelViewController:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"ReloadTable" 
        object:nil];

Here you can also send custom object instead of nil parameter. But be care full about removal of NSNotification observer.
```

Comment: Hello can any one tell me?